# Blazor calling await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync() blocks UI thread in DEBUG mode

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-jsruntime

In my blazor app I am trying to open a url (constructed dynamically) in a new tab on the onClick event. When I click the anchor tag, the page is opened in a new tab but the browser thread gets frozen.
This usually happens after the first try, but sometimes happens after multiple tries

This seems to be an older issue that was marked as resolved but apparently it's [still happening](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28577):

I am using Visual Studio 2022 with dotnet 6.

## My code

**html code**

```
<a href=""
   onclick="@(async () => await OpenUrlInNewTab())"
   @onclick:preventDefault>
   Open url in new tab
</a>
```

**c# code**

```
@functions {

    async Task OpenUrlInNewTab()
    {
        var url = "https://www.google.com";
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("open", url, "_blank");
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to understand what the problem is and how it can be solved. So far the issue happens only locally in DEBUG mode, but works in our staging environment.

Comment: To clarify, the GitHub issue you linked to is marked as closed, not resolved. An MS engineer thinks it's a Chromium bug. What browser are you using? Is it Edge or Chrome?

Comment: @mamift Thanks for highlighting that up. I was able to reproduce it in Edge (uses Chromium) and Chrome. Couldn't reproduce it in Firefox though